# How can I resolve the 'UnsupportedMediaType' error when attempting to add an attachment to an issue in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, jira-rest-api

How can I resolve the `UnsupportedMediaType` error when attempting to add an attachment to an issue in .NET? I have encountered this issue while working with Jira integration in my code. I've already searched the official Jira documentation for a solution, but I couldn't find any relevant information to address this problem.

```
public async Task AddAttachmentAsync(string issueKey, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        var fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        var request = new RestRequest($"/rest/api/3/issue/{issueKey}/attachments", Method.Post);

        request.AddHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");

        request.AddFile("file", fileData, fileName, "multipart/form-data");

        var response = await _client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error adding attachment: {response.StatusCode} - {response.Content}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I tried converting the file to base64 and adding a content type to the request header.

Comment: Are you sure your end point is post may it be put or something else?

Comment: Yes, I searched in the official Jira REST API documentation, and it says that it should be done using the POST method.